# Json to csv converter (IE 8+)

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, internet-explorer, csv

I am using the JSONToCSVConvertor tool (which is actually a javascript function) from http://www.hybridplanet.co.in/tutorial/javascript/how-to-create-csv-or-excel-file-from-json-via-javascript to convert a Json response to csv format.
In Firefox and Chrome (currently using versions 30 and 34, respectively) the csv file is generated and made available for download **without any issues whatsoever**.
However, in IE (8+) the file is neither generated nor downloaded.
Particularly, in IE 8, the following line throws an error:

> **link.style = "visibility:hidden"; --> "Member not found"**

Where as in IE 9, IE 10, and IE 11, a blank page is opened without any results.
Any hints or advice to make this work will be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking now for solution.
As much as I know IE doesn't support "uri" methods because of safety for users :(